# String to list Python

Tags: python, string, list

I have a string like

```
res_string= '[\n  "admin_name",\n  "admin_pass",\n  "https://google.com",\n  "managed_acc_id"\n]'
```

Now I want to convert this into a list(say `res_list`) such that I can retrieve admin_name, admin_pass, etc as an index.

I.e.

```
res_list[0]='admin_name'
res_list[1]='admin_pass'
res_list[2]='https://google.com'
res_list[3]='managed_acc_id'
```

One way to achieve this is to use split/replace logic.

What will the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: You can use `json.loads` or `ast.literal_eval`

Comment: @VladimirVilimaitis No, you don't use `eval()` on data.

Comment: @VladimirVilimaitis https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best is to use `liter_eval` from `ast`:

```
>>> import ast
>>> res_string= '[\n  "admin_name",\n  "admin_pass",\n  "https://google.com",\n  "managed_acc_id"\n]'
>>> ast.literal_eval(res_string)
['admin_name', 'admin_pass', 'https://google.com', 'managed_acc_id']
```

or `loads` from `json`:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads(res_string)
['admin_name', 'admin_pass', 'https://google.com', 'managed_acc_id']
```

Comment: Could you explain why that would be the best option?

Comment: @Sabsa Because it's safe (comparing to `eval()`), simple and explicit (comparing to the split/replace solution)

Comment: Yes, but here is an answer that compares execution time and it is not fast compared to json or no import at all. So again, what would make literal_eval the _best_ option? https://stackoverflow.com/a/55931430/10557420

Comment: @Sabsa This answer compares execution times of 100k executions. I believe OPs problem is noticeably smaller hence the difference between `liter_eval`, `json` and split/replace is negligible in regards to execution time. Yes, `json` solution might be as good in this case, I'll add it to the answer.